# Using Oauth 2 Google

Tags: javascript, angular, oauth, google-oauth, google-authentication

I'm trying to use Google API to authenticate users. I'm got to authenticate, but I'm don't know how to redirect users after Sign In and how to Sign Out.

I'm try to use Google documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in. But I've got an error: `Cannot read property 'getAuthInstance' of undefined`.

Here is the code:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<script>
    var redirectUri = 'http://localhost:4200/list';
    function onSignIn(googleUser) {

        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
        console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
    }
    function signOut() {
        var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        auth2.signOut().then(function () {
            console.log('User signed out.');
        });
    }
</script>
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either the `gapi.auth2.init()` method in your script or have `<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">` in your `<head>`.

Your code would look like this:

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<script>
    var redirectUri = 'http://localhost:4200/list';
    function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
        console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
    }
    function signOut() {
        var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        auth2.signOut().then(function () {
            console.log('User signed out.');
        });
    }
</script>
```

More info on the `gapi.auth2.init()` method: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2initwzxhzdk19paramswzxhzdk20